# xdmp:eval returning different result for different ML versions

Tags: xquery, marklogic

In ML 9.0-8 version, expression `xdmp:eval("(3298534883328) div 1024 div 1024 div 1024 ")` return 0.
However in ML 9.0-7 the same expression returns 3072.

Similarly, in ML 9.0-8 version expression `xdmp:eval("(3298534883328) div 1024 ")` return 322122382 but in ML 9.0-7 version the same expression returns 3221225472

Why there is the difference of 3072 with different versions?

Comment: This issue is resolved in 9.0.9 and later. No workarounds needed if you upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `xs:decimal` division is returning incorrect results. This is an extremely large number, so I would guess that it is the result of some sort of overflow.

Each of the the following expressions yield the `xs:decimal` value `322122382.272474584` in later versions of MarkLogic, instead of `3221225472` that is returned in earlier versions.

```
3298534883328 div 1024 ,
xs:integer(3298534883328) div 1024,
xs:decimal(3298534883328) div 1024,
xs:long(3298534883328) div 1024
```

**As a workaround, you can coerce the expected value by explicitly evaluating either the left hand or the right hand number as an `xs:double` or `xs:float` by using [fn:number()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-number), [`xs:numeric()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#numeric-types), `xs:double()`, or `xs:float()`.**

Each of the following returns the expected answer `3072`:

```
fn:number(3298534883328) div 1024 div 1024 div 1024,
xs:numeric(3298534883328) div 1024 div 1024 div 1024,
xs:double(3298534883328) div 1024 div 1024 div 1024,
xs:float(3298534883328) div 1024 div 1024 div 1024,

3298534883328 div fn:number(1024) div 1024 div 1024,
3298534883328 div xs:numeric(1024) div 1024 div 1024,
3298534883328 div xs:double(1024) div 1024 div 1024,
3298534883328 div xs:float(1024) div 1024 div 1024
```